# Xerces thread safety?

Tags: c++, multithreading, xerces

taken from here:
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/faq-parse-3.html#faq-6

> When two or more parser instances exist in a process, the instances can be used 
>   concurrently, without external synchronization. That is, in an application containing two 
>   parsers and two threads, one parser can be running within the first thread concurrently with 
>   the second parser running within the second thread.

But the below code fails whenever the QMutex is commented and does not whenever it is used.

```
bool reports::validateSchema( QString fileName )
{
    // QMutexLocker lock( &xercesMutex );
    try
    {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        this->throw_report_exception(__FILE__,__LINE__,__TIME__,__DATE__,"reports::validateSchema",
                                     "unable to initialize Xerces Plateform");
        return false;
    }


    const char* const xsd = "full absloute path to .xsd ==> hard written";

    XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser();

    try
    {
        parser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);
        parser->setDoSchema(true);
        parser->setDoNamespaces(true);
        parser->setValidationConstraintFatal(true);
        parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Auto);

        ParserErrorHandler errHandler;
        parser->setErrorHandler(&errHandler);

        parser->cacheGrammarFromParse(true);
        parser->loadGrammar(xsd,Grammar::SchemaGrammarType,true);


        parser->parse(fileName.toStdString().c_str());
        std::cout << parser->getErrorCount() << std::endl;
        if(parser->getErrorCount()!=0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (const XMLException& toCatch)
    {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
        std::cout << "Exception message is: \n"
                << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);
        return false;
    }
    catch (const DOMException& toCatch)
    {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.msg);
        std::cout << "Exception message is: \n"
                << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);
        return false;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Unexpected Exception \n" ;
        return false;
    }

    delete parser;
    XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();


    return true;
}
```

What am I missing ?

The functions get executed hundreds of times and at some point, I'm getting a segfault from either:

```
XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser();
```

or

```
parser->loadGrammar(xsd,Grammar::SchemaGrammarType,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

A quote from the same FAQ answer you refer to:

> The application also needs to guarantee that the XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize() and 
>   XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate() methods are called from the same thread (usually the 
>   initial thread executing main()) or proper synchronization is performed by the application
>   if multiple threads call XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize() and XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate() 
>   concurrently.